# Prove or disprove $f(n)-g(n)=O(s(n)-r(n))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f(n)=O(s(n))$ and $g(n)=O(r(n))$ use the formal definition of the asymptotic notations. Can anyone help me with this with a proof or a counter example. I am lost on this one.

Comment: Think $s(n) = r(n)$. What then?

Comment: I defined it. just now thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in O(x^2),x/2\in O(x^2)$ but $x-x/2=x/2\notin O(x^2-x^2)$.